# How to call a delete function with parameter(_id) outside the class in react js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

This is what I have tried? I wanted to **call the deleteDebt() function in the code. But I can't pass the function to const Debt.** (Outside the class) How can I do that?

Here I want to pass the props.debt._id through the function. Because I want to delete the particular row in the table with it's _id.

```
const Debt = props => (



    <tr>
        <td>{props.debt.fullName}</td>
        <td>{props.debt.damount}</td>
        <td>
            <button className="btn btn-danger btn-info  " type="delete" onClick={() => this.deleteDebtor(props.debt._id)}>DELETE</button>

        </td>
    </tr>
)



export default class profile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.deleteDebtor = this.deleteDebtor.bind(this);



        this.state = {
            fullName: '',
            damount: '',
            users: []
        }
    }
```

this is where i get data from the database.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('url')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ users: response.data.data });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
```

this is where i make the table.

```
    UserList() {

            // console.log(this.state.users);
            return this.state.users.map(function (currentDebt, i) {

                return <Debt debt={currentDebt} key={i} />;
            }


    }
```

this is the deleteDebt() function.

```
    deleteDebtor(data) {
        axios.delete('url' + data)


    }
```

this is rendering part

```
 render() {


        return (


            <React.Fragment>

                <div >
                                       <table } >
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Name </th>
                                                    <th>Amount</th>

                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>

                                                {this.UserList()}
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `Debt` component, there is no such thing as `this.deleteDebtor`, so `onClick={() => this.deleteDebtor(props.debt._id)}` will not work.

Comment: So how can I pass that function to the Debt component from the below profile class?

Comment: When you render the Debt component, pass the function as a prop.

Comment: @BhagyaKumaranayake See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a reference to the `this.deleteDebtor` as props.

```
<Debt delete={this.deleteDebtor} debt={currentDebt} key={i} />;

const Debt = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.debt.fullName}</td>
    <td>{props.debt.damount}</td>
    <td>
      <button className="btn btn-danger btn-info  " type="delete" onClick={() => props.delete(props.debt._id)}>DELETE</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
)
```

Note that this will re-render the component whenever the parent re-renders because a new function gets created on each render.
You can use `React.memo` to prevent that:

```
const Debt = React.memo(props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.debt.fullName}</td>
    <td>{props.debt.damount}</td>
    <td>
      <button className="btn btn-danger btn-info  " type="delete" onClick={() => props.delete(props.debt._id)}>DELETE</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
));
```

**update**

I think you have a scoping issue change the normal function inside `map` into an arrow function:

```
UserList() {
  // console.log(this.state.users);
  return this.state.users.map((currentDebt, i) => {
    return <Debt delete={this.deleteDebtor} debt={currentDebt} key={i} />;
  });
}
```

Comment: I treid. But I got this kind of error in the browser. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteDebtor' of undefined". So should I bind this function to props or anything else? If so, How can I bind that to props?

Comment: I changed the code according to your updated code. Then the error was gone. But when I click the DELETE button, I get this error. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined". It's in the Debt component's onClick(). @Ramesh

Comment: @BhagyaKumaranayake If you pass everything correctly you shouldn't get this error. I can't help you anymore unless I see your entire code. You can replicate your issue in a `stackblitz` or `codesandbox` and send the link if you have time. I'll look into it.

Comment: here is another question. In this code i get data from a url in componentDidMount() and pass its' data in Userlist() using "users". Now I want to pass the data from two url s. It means I get data from two collections. So I just want to send both url s' data from Userlist() as I use both collections data to make the table. So do you have an idea about the way that I can do it? @Ramesh

Comment: @BhagyaKumaranayake See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61038630/how-to-optimally-combine-multiple-axios-responses). You can use `axios.all` and pass all the axios requests in an array and that will resolve when all of the requests are resolved and then you will get an argument which is an array having the data of each resolved request and you can use it as you want.