# How to optimally combine multiple axios responses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am working with a React app. I have to create 2 objects using responses from 3 different APIs. For example:

1. DataObject1 will be created using API1 and API2
2. DataObject2 will be created using API1, API2, and API3

So, I am thinking about what would be the most optimal way of doing this by making sure 1 call each API only once.

I was thinking this:

```
const requestOne = axios.get(API1);
const requestTwo = axios.get(API2);
const requestThree = axios.get(API3);

axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
  const dataObject1 = createDataObject1(responses[0], responses[1]);
  const dataObject2 = createDataObject2(responses[0], responses[1], responses[2]);
  // use/access the results 
})).catch(errors => {
  // react on errors.
})

const createDataObject1 = (response1, response2) => { //Combine required data and return dataObject1 }
const createDataObject2 = (response1, response2, response3) => { //Combine required data and return dataObject2 }
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Update the question with the response you get and also how the `dataObject1` and `dataObject2` should look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks fine.

You can change this

```
axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
  const dataObject1 = createDataObject1(responses[0], responses[1]);
  const dataObject2 = createDataObject2(responses[0], responses[1], responses[2]);
  // use/access the results 
})).catch(errors => {
  // react on errors.
})
```

to

```
axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree]).then((response) => {
  const dataObject1 = createDataObject1(responses[0], responses[1]);
  const dataObject2 = createDataObject2(responses[0], responses[1], responses[2]);
  // use/access the results 
}).catch(errors => {
  // react on errors.
})
```

because it is unnecessary to spread and rest.

If you don't want to use them like `responses[0]`, `responses[1]`, etc then you can use:

```
axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree]).then(axios.spread((response1, response2, response3) => {
  const dataObject1 = createDataObject1(response1, response2);
  const dataObject2 = createDataObject2(response1, response2,response3);
  // use/access the results 
})).catch(errors => {
  // react on errors.
})
```

Comment: This answer seems fine to me. That's all there is to it, there's nothing to optimize. On a deeper level, before and after this action is dispatched, I think the OP needs more clarity how Redux and async calls are working within their system.

Comment: Only the second example using `spread` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using thunk middleware to make async calls in Redux? I don't want to assume that you are, but that seems like a good basic approach here.

```
const requestOne = axios.get(API1);
const requestTwo = axios.get(API2);
const requestThree = axios.get(API3);
```

Okay. So now `requestOne.data` has the result of making the axios get request. Or, would if the thunk creator was async and the code was `const requestOne = await axios.get(API1);`

Do you need to parse the data further from request___.data ?

If not you can just have

```
const dataObj1 = { response1: requestOne.data, response2: requestTwo.data }
const dataObj2 = { ... dataObject1, response3: requestThree.data };
```

Full answer:

```
// store/yourFile.js code
export const YourThunkCreator = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const const requestOne = await axios.get(API1);
    // other axios requests
    const dataObj1 = { response1: requestOne.data, response2: requestTwo.data }
    const dataObj2 = { ... dataObject1, response3: requestThree.data };
    // other code
    dispatch(// to Redux Store);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

Comment: But how I am going to dispatch to two different reducers?

Comment: @Blueboye you would have one action, with one action type ('YOUR_ACTION'), and both reducers would respond appropriately do that one action.

Remember all actions pass through all reducers.